# Devise not saving parameters that are already sanitized in App Controller Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration, strong-parameters

My registrations are working properly, I have 3 custom fields: `name, avatar, avatar_cache`.

Only the `:name` custom field is giving me a: 
`Unpermitted parameters: name` in console.

I already sanitized strong parameters in Application Controller and the avatar / avatar_cache are saving correctly. Am I missing something?

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :email, :password, :current_password, :password_confirmation) }
  end
```

Comment: are you getting same error in the application?

Comment: @KikeIsasiVelasco Why are you redefining `configure_permitted_parameters`, I see two separate method definitions, one sanitizing `sign_up` params and other `account_update` ? Or is it just a typo here?

Comment: Does your `User` have `:name` attribute? check it in the console

Comment: Because one is for updating users account and the other is for registration purposes, thats what I've read in a couple of posts that I had to do. @KirtiThorat

Comment: Yes it does: 

     `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"V5ACfT1uI1Z3o2VypwXe98pcVqRDIHNz0zJF/5cF/0w=", "user"=>{"name"=>"Kike", "email"=>"kikeisasxxi@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Crear cuenta"}
Unpermitted parameters: name
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN`

Comment: in `Rails console`, if you simply type `User`, it will list all the attributes for User. is `:name` included?

Comment: And user has :name column in users table

Comment: Yes it does `User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, provider: string, uid: string, photo: string, location: string, name: string, avatar: string)`

Comment: @KikeIsasiVelasco Read my answer, to get an idea of why redefining the same method is not going to work in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you have redefined the method `configure_permitted_parameters`, which is why Ruby is picking the latest method definition i.e., the one which whitelists attributes for `account_update`. So, when you try to `sign_up` with custom attribute `name`, you would receive

`Unpermitted parameters: name` warning

as because of the overwriting the method `configure_permitted_parameters`, devise has no idea about the custom attributes that should have been whitelisted for `sign_up`

Your `configure_permitted_parameters` method should look like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  ## ...

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :email, :password, :current_password, :password_confirmation) } 
  end
end
```